# Quick Sort Algorithm When Partition is Constant Time

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis, quicksort

I ran into a question about Quick Sort Algorithm.

Suppose in Quick Sort, Partition procedure take C times, (need constant time). if we use random data as input, what is the order (time complexity) of Randomized-Quick Sort?

any hint or solution highly appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried and where did you get stuck? Have you read and understood the "normal" Quicksort analysis? What happens if you replace the "normal" partitioning cost with something else?

Comment: if i know it, i didnt ask

Comment: Cross-posted: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26207040/781723, https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/29357/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Since the runtime for each recursive call is dominated by the runtime of partition, the runtime of your modified algorithm will be $C$ times the total number of recursive calls. The latter number is independent of the input and relatively easy to determine, by looking at the elements that are not taken into the recursive calls. (Trying to solve this via a recurrence relation is significantly harder.)

Comment: Dear FranW, i know this fact. but in create a recurrence and solve it get stuck.

Comment: @HamidKir If you know this, why didn't you mention it in the question, so you'd get hints that adress the point, you are struggling with?

Comment: i couldent try to wrote a recurrence relation and solve it. i think it's not need on question.

Comment: Dear @FranW, would you please complete your answeR?

Comment: @HamidKir Frank is right: your question should include how far you got. For instance, we have reference material on solving recurrences.

Comment: @HamidKir If you are not willing to put work in your question, why should I be willing to put work into helping you? (Also, I think the hint is sufficient to find the answer.)